# AWS Domain Transfer stuck in Step 14

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I had initiated a domain transfer on Amazon. The WHOIS records show that the domain is now transferred to GANDI (AWS technical domain provider).

However, for the past 5 days, I've been seeing the domain in "Pending Requests", and stuck in step 14 with the message: **Domain transfer in progress: Sent email to registrant contact: transfer is complete (step 14 of 14)**.

But I didn't receive any email on the registrant contact, and neither is the domain moving to the "Registered domains" section in the AWS Route 53 console.

How long does this usually take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took exactly **8 working days** by the clock. But the domain transfer is now complete.

Comment: Did you ask the AWS support for help? I have a domain transfer stuck. Its been 1 day but I heavily rely on that domain and I can't use it.